# Dynamic Sender Profile Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I wrote the following script to pull in a Sales reps name.

```
%%[
    
var @Territory, @mdmidKey, @SalesRep
    
set @mdmidKey = [mdmid]
set @Territory = Lookup("BR_Call","Territory_vod__c","External_Id_vod__c",@mdmidKey)
set @SalesRep = Lookup("TerritoryVOD","SalesRep","Territory__vod__c",@Territory)

IF Empty(@SalesRep) THEN
  SET @SalesRep = "Company X"
ENDIF
     
]%%

%%=v(@SalesRep)=%%
```

The issue I am running into is that this work perfectly fine when I have it in an email and I am previewing my subscribers. When I put the script into my Sender Name for my dynamic sender profile, I get an error message:

> "TEST SalesRep Dynamic Sender External Key: xxxx Invalid Sender
> Profile state. ClientID: xxxxxxx SenderProfileID:
> 80fb3486-712a-fb11-a2f2-1422eg948a8d Sender Profile Name: TEST
> SalesRep Dynamic Sender CustomerKey: xxxx The FromName AMPScript
> contains the following errorsScript SET Statement Invalid - "set
> @mdmidKey = [mdmid]""

It seems it does not like my `set @mdmidKey = [mdmid] line`. Is there a different way to have this formatted to work for a dynamic sender profile for the sender name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked this way:

Create a CodeSnippet Block. Give it a Customer_Key. Let's say its "GLOBAL_SENDPROFILE_FROMNAME".

Write all logic in that Codesnippet block via Ampscript.
When you are sending each and every dataextension used for sending needs to have a column named mdmid, otherwise your calls most likely will return nothing. And this value always needs to be filled.

Go to your sender profile (the @SalesRep variable needs to be inside your codesnippet block) and insert this.

```
%%=ContentBlockbyKey("GLOBAL_SENDPROFILE_FROMNAME")=%% %%=v(@SalesRep)=%%
```

Also be aware of the fact what happens if your code that sets the variable @territory will not receive any records.